# How to store HTML content within an array for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, rhapsody

My aim is to have a single web page which changes back and forth between two pieces of code every 60 seconds. I am able to do this with two urls/webpages using content refresh, however, ideally I am trying to include it all in one javascript file.

page1content and page2content indicate where I would want to insert the html code within the array. The HTML code is run within a js filter using Rhapsody Integration engine.

Any thoughts on how I might be able to get html content to switch between the two in a continous loop?

```
var next = output.append(input[0]);

var html = "";
html = html + "<style>";
html = html + "<span id=\"flicker\"></span>";
html = html + "</style>";

var pageContent = ["page1content", "page2content"];
var count = 0;

function changeContent() {
    $("#flicker").text(pageContent[count]);
    count < 2 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeContent, 60000);

XMLData.setText(HTMLBody,'UTF8');
```

Comment: Try appending DOM string - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Comment: You have presented code, but not explained what in that code fails to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below:

```js
const pageContent = [
` <p>This is from page 1.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph from page 1.</p>`, 
` <p>This is from page 2.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph from page 2.</p>`];
let count = 0;

function changeContent() {
    $("#flicker").html(pageContent[count]);
    count++; count %= 2;
}
setInterval(changeContent, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flicker"></div>
```

**P.S:** Setting the interval to 5 seconds to showcase the functionality more quickly

Comment: `count++; count %= 2;` shortens your code by quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks! @connexo

Comment: @Salvino that makes sense, however it's just shortening the code and achieving what I already have? How do I store HTML code within the array (i.e. I can't just copy and paste it into the tags or that won't work). I have to keep the var html section too as this is how the html code must be run within our integration engine

Comment: @dtab3 you can directly replace the page1conent with your html strings using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Let me update the answer to show you.